# WPF: set column width from userControl

Tags: c#, wpf

How to reference the width of a column from its nested user control?

I have a Grid-Layout using Grid.ColumnDefinitions:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The columns got user-controls:

```
<u:box Grid.Column:0 x:Name="one" Count="{Binding Path=Count}">
<u:box Grid.Column:1 x:Name="two" Count="{Binding Path=Count}">
```

I have a variable "Count" inside the userControl that sets the amount of Elements to show.
If Count = 1, I'd like to set the Column-Definition of the second userControl to "0". To make it desappear. If Count = 0 , bot width should be set to "0" and if Count = 2, no column-width should be set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way of achieving your results is giving the grid an explicit name, and setting up a multivalue converter to handle the sizing the width.

The multivalue converter will used when binding to the Count.
The First binding will take in the Actual count. 
The second binding should take in a indicator value that defines the column e.g. a string value ("one","two","three"). 
The third binding should bind to the actual grid, using the grid name.

```
<u:box Grid.Column:0 x:Name="one">
 <u:box.Count>
   <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}" 
ConverterParameter="one">
     <Binding Path="Count"/>
     <Binding ElementName="GridName"/>
  </MultiBinding>
 </u:box.Count>
</u:box>
```

With all three of these values in your mutlivalue converter you should have enough information to determine how to size the grid columns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I have to set the multivalue converter to in the definition of the column definition?

Comment: i have updated the comment, to show an example of the bidning.